# Swift: UITableView? does not have a member named reloadData

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing a basic intro to Swift course, and keep getting stuck on this 'to-do list' app task.

I've had to put a ? after creating an IB OUtlet ( @IBOutlet var tasksTable:UITableView? ) to stop it from crashing, but this has meant that I've got the error 'UITableView? does not have a member named reloadData' after this function:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tasksTable.reloadData()
```

Anyone know what's going on here? Apologies for the simple question - I'm pretty new to this.

p.s I'm using Swift 6.1

Full code is below.

Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

var toDoItems :[String] = []

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tasksTable:UITableView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return toDoItems.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell  = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel.text = "Example"

    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tasksTable.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: What happens when you write `tasksTable?.reloadData()` or `tasksTable!.reloadData()`, does the error go away?

Comment: "I've had to put a ? after creating an IB OUtlet [...] to stop it from crashing" <- Is this the Swift equivalent of adding `retain` calls at random places until it stops crashing? I would recommend to stop the intro course and instead I would read the Swift Book by Apple.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I think it's related to how in interface builder/storyboard, you may or may not have connected the UI element to the property in source code, hence the '?' optional requirement, otherwise, probably that is Swift's way of working with Interface Builder vs Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

`tasksTable` in an optional, so you should use optional chaining and write `tasksTable?.reloadData()`. Since after `awakeFromNib`, `tasksTable` will always be non-nil, you can also type your outlet `UITableView!` to avoid this.

Comment: Are you missing a '?' after `tasksTable` there ? (I'm new to Swift too).

Comment: Typing an answer in Swift, using a phone with possibly Swift-key and updated your answer pretty Swiftly :D triple hit combo! lol.

Comment: Just tried this, but it is still failing. If I put a ? after tasksTable, what should I do with the tasksTable: UITableView at the top?

Comment: If you declare tasksTable as UITableView? (optional) then you need to use optional chaining (tasksTable?.reloadData()). If you declare it as implicitly unwrapped optional (UITableView!) then you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tasksTable?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Just tried that but build is still failing. Any other ideas?

Comment: First big of the log: 2014-11-26 07:23:08.178 To Do List v2[16794:1411999] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<To_Do_List_v2.FirstViewController 0x7f9b49c7f6e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tasksTable.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: That's not a build failure, that's a runtime error. It really is a different problem and you should write it up as a new problem.